# CSS Mobile Definition Not Applying?

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a site [here](http://potion.x10host.com/blog/). It works great on all screens except mobile where the slogan is too large. So i added a mobile css definition for the slogan "Always coding and brewing up something good" but on my phone it does nothing? I am using bootstrap but only with the grid and responsive elements. The css I applied is the below in question is:

```html
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
 .grabber{
  font-size: 12px;
 }

}
```

Comment: do you have the viewport in the header?

Comment: yes its added. still not sure why it isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined in your stylesheet.css a following order of styles:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    .grabber{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
.grabber{
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'black_roseregular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

and due to processing css-rules consequentially latest font size style applied to .grabber will be `font-size: 2em;`. All you need is to swap these statements like this:

```
.grabber{
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'black_roseregular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    .grabber{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```